# Issues executing code on higher API levels Android

Tags: android, sdk, apk, version

My minSDK version is 16 and my targetSDK version is 27. The compileSDK version is 28.

Since the targetSDK version is 27 it should run on Oreo(8.0.0) without issues but some of the features don't work as intended. However they do work fine on Nougat.
Why is this so?

Answer (score 0):

The targetSDK is stating what you built in the app to be able to handle. So, there might be a new feature in API 28 and you're saying your code was build against API 27 so if you're running on API 28 and there is support on 28 for how you used the api before, then it will try to maintain your API 27 coded behavior.  There still exists the possibility your API 27 code will result in different or wrong behavior if run on API 28 though.

Please review the documentation as well:

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element

"To maintain your application along with each Android release, you should increase the value of this attribute to match the latest API level, then thoroughly test your application on the corresponding platform version."